# How to implement ILoggerFactory

Tags: asp.net, logging, .net-8.0

I understand that `ILoggerFactory` gives me the ability to create logger provider by name.

How exactly do I it?

Let's say I have `LoggerProvider1` and `LoggerProvider2`.

This is my `Program.cs` file:

```
srv.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.ClearProviders();
    builder.AddProvider(new LoggerProvider1());
    builder.AddProvider(new LoggerProvider2());
});
```

What do I need to do here?

```
public class MyFactory : ILoggerFactory
{
}
```

Where to load `MyFactory` in `Program.cs` file?

How to call `ILoggerFactory` like this

```
ILoggerFactory factory;
factory.CreateLogger<HomeController>("LoggerProvider1");
factory.CreateLogger<HomeController>("LoggerProvider2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Factory is the highest level in logging. By default Asp.Net adds its instance to the services once you build your application.

LoggerProvider is middle level of this workflow. There can be one or multiple providers inside factory and their job is to create `Logger` instances which are used to log data.

Logger is lowest level of logging and it is the one you need to interact with to log data.

Since .NET has created factory for you, you need to add provider to it.
You do that with code you wrote:

```
srv.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.ClearProviders();
    builder.AddProvider(new LoggerProvider1());
    builder.AddProvider(new LoggerProvider2());
});
```

Only thing that is left to do is to get instance of `ILogger` (which will be created automatically by provider) using dependency injection.

So if you want to log something in `MyClass` you would do it like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(ILogger logger)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Hello from logger");
    }
}
```

Or more common:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Hello from logger");
    }
}
```

To be able to use it in other methods pull it out:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;
    public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Log()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Hello from another method");
    }

}
```